# What size drill motor should I buy?

Tags: drill, powertools, power

Looking to buy a non-professional (occasional home DIY use) multi-purpose power-drill like the 'Skil' range by Bosche (although I am open to other brand / makes that fit my budget). I have an option of buying 300W, 450W and 650W. I rarely (if ever) need to drill metal -- but do need to drill wood and masonry (including concrete). I am almost convinced that the 300W would perhaps be too underpowered, though I am not sure by any measure. The model 450W and 650W models seem to have only 2 differences, i.e.:

- 650W model claims to be able to drill 13mm in steel, while 450W claims 10mm
- 650W model has an extra side handle, I guess to get a better grip while using 2 hands

The price difference between 450W and 650W is significant enough to consider saving the money for other necessary tools for my tool box, unless the additional power is justified.

Comment: for concrete you need a hammer function

Comment: Forgot to mention that both 450 and 650W models have hammer action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am more into features than power.

Most important feature is multi speed function where the trigger is a speed control.
Next is chuck size. Not just max size but also min bit size
Reversible is cool but I don't really use it.
Lastly make is a factor and generally you get what you pay for. On the DIY side drills last years. Just pay the few extra bucks, you will never regret it. But also remember you don't need pro grade that's overkill. 450 sounds ok. I have 3 - 550 watt drills and they are great.

Comment: Thanks @Hightower. The 450 and 550W multi-purpose drills (reversible, variable-speed, hammer action supporting) I am considering, can screw-on and unscrew. If your drills have such capabilities, wanted to know if you've tried using it with screws. I am particularly interested to see if these drills can unscrew somewhat rusty, highly tightened screws that are screwed into hardwood ? This is in fact the number one reason I am looking for these drills.

Comment: Really hard to say, I think it would be dependant on the each drill, however with variable speed, the low speeds are often not high torque, so you would get most power by pressing hard on the trigger and your threads would get damaged, to get the screws in, is easy (using those drywall/decking drivers). Have you tried cordless drills for that purpose, they have better low speed control with higher torque.

Comment: The cordless screw drill with low torque that I checked, is 2.5x the price of the one I am considering buying, so definitely out of my budget. However I can check if renting one of those might be a possibility.